# Django testing, after login still get response 302, expecting 200

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm testing django app login part.
my work flow is client.get('/run/experiment/1') -> response 302, redirect to login page -> client.post('loginpage', {'username': 'tester', 'password': 'tester'}) -> client.get('/run/experiment/1') -> response 200.
I have tested this flow in shell (type and execute the command line by line), and it worked as expected.
But when I write the test file, even after post the login, I still got the status 302 when trying to client.get.
Here is my code:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class TestRunRequireLogin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_rerun_not_login(self):
        response = self.client.get('/experiment/1')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_rerun_login(self):
        self.client.post('/accounts/login/?next=/run/experiment/1', {'username': 'tester', 'password': 'tester'})
        response = self.client.get('/experiment/1')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

So my question is when in test_rerun_login, why I still got 302 after login

Comment: So my question is when in test_rerun_login, why I still got 302 after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests are run against an empty database. You need to create a user in the `setUp` method.

Comment: Yes, I found I need to create a user in setUp(), and use this temp user to login in my test. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have users? Do you have a user with username `tester` and password `tester`? If so you need to create them in your testcase.

Might be handy to post your view up there.Can you print the form.errors? You might find the answer there.

Comment: I have user with the name and password tester, and my test in shell works as expected.
>>>from django.test import Client >>>client = Client() >>>response = client.get('/run/experiment/1') >>>response.status_code, I got 302 here, >>>client.post('/accounts/login/?next=/run/experiment/1', {'username': 'tester', 'password': 'tester'}) >>>response = client.get('/run/experiment/1') >>>response.status_code, I got 200.But this doesn't work in the test file.

Comment: The test db isn't the same as the db you use in your shell. It's empty.

Comment: I see, it works now. I created a user in setUp(), and use that new added credential, and after client.post the login, my client.get gave me response 200. Thanks!